# IntelliJ svn integration: IntelliJ says commit failed, but the commit actually succeded. Why?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, commit

IntelliJ svn integration: IntelliJ says commit failed, but the commit actually succeded.

I get 0 files committed. 1 file failed to commit:

However when I check my remote repository the commit has actually been registered (I assume correctly). Why is this? Is it something to worry about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what caused the problem, but simple update to IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.2 solved it.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2 with TortoiseSVN 1.9.4. Both `Use command line client` on or off produce the same error. Any idea? (All are x64 and on x64 system)

Comment: The Intellij IDEA  updated to 2016.1.3 but the problem is persisted. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Ocassionally, IntelliJ and svn can have such problems where they don't appear to synchronize correctly.

Does the problem occur just once, or every time you commit?

Some things to try:
- Update your project (ctrl-T) before you commit
- Go to the (9) Changes pane -> `Local` tab and hit refresh
- Go to the (9) Chanages pane -> `Subversion working copies` tab and use the `Cleanup` option
- Failing that, invalidate the cache in IntelliJ and restart

Those steps should give you a more stable integration between intelliJ and svn.

Remember to also upgrade intellij and svn client to latest appropriate versions as needed.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't help. The error always shows up, but the change is still always committed.

Comment: What version of svn client and intellij are you using?

Comment: IntelliJ 13.1.5 and svn 1.8.8

Comment: Do u know if you are using "command line client", or not? Perhaps toggle this feature?

Comment: I use IntelliJ svn integration.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with your language settings. I had the same error until I started IntelliJ (our Android Studio for that matter) until I set my LANG environment to C before starting IntelliJ:

```
export LANG=C
export LC_MESSAGES=C
```